# Passing names of class fields to a private sub to update in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, class

I thought this might be simple to achieve, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

I have a series of fields within a class that I want to check the value of.  So instead of writing the same if ... then ... else statement I thought passing this through a private method would be ideal.

```
Private Sub checkParameter(ByRef p_param As Object, ByRef p_private_field As Object, p_exception As String)

        If Not p_param Then
            Throw New Exception(p_exception)
        Else
            p_private_field = p_param
        End If
    End Sub
```

Of course the problem is that I want the p_private_field to be the actual private field I am passing in.

So if I called the method with the following code:

```
checkParameter(i_input_folder, "p_input_folder", "Input folder must be supplied")
```

Then the method would check that i_input_folder did have a value and if so then assign it to the private field p_input_folder and if not throw the exception with the message provided.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Rather than code external to the class doing the checking consider a method like `IsValid` or `IsComplete` so the class can check itself, by itself.

Answer (score -1):

Seems just like a little typo

```
checkParameter(i_input_folder, "p_input_folder", "Input folder must be supplied")
```

You pass in your second parameter as string (the name of the filed i guess), but you have to pass the object itself

```
checkParameter(i_input_folder, p_input_folder, "Input folder must be supplied")
```

Comment: HI David, I did actually try that first of all but when debugging the code an empty string is passed in rather than the reference to the object itself.  I was thinking that I needed to enclose the reference name, as in PHP {} to denote a class field.  thanks for looking though.

Comment: @EvilKermitSaurus does p_input_folder already has a value? If its value is an empty string everything should fine

Comment: p_input_folder is the name of the class field that I want to update with the value of i_input_folder.  So when in the method the code I want p_private_field = p_param to mean p_input_folder = i_input_folder.  I hope that makes sense??